# How do you embed a hover button with clickable link in a Tweet?

Tags: twitter

How do you create a button in a tweet below an image, like this: https://twitter.com/antisempolicy/status/1317013219437850624

Note the button below with text "Tweet #standuptohate" button with hover-over functionality.

Answer (score 0):

That Tweet is created via a Twitter Ads partner - you can create something similar using ads.twitter.com if you sign up as an advertiser.